# delete bigquery table from spark by using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-bigquery

Is there a way to drop a BigQuery table from Spark by using Scala?

I only find ways to read and write BigQuery table from Spark by using Scala from the example here:
https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example

Can someone provide an example to drop a BigQuery table? For example, I can drop a table in BigQuery console using this statement "`drop table if exists projectid1.dataset1.table1`".

Please note that my purpose of removing the existing table is NOT to overwrite. I simply want to remove it. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: why you want to do it from Spark? Spark is analytics engine, not JDBC or SQL Developer.

Comment: @MikhailIonkin It is a step in the analytics process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the [BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries):

```
import com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.{BigQueryOptions, TableId}

val bq = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService() 
val table = bq.getTable(TableId.of("projectid1", "dataset1", "table1"))
if(table != null) {
  table.delete()
}
```

Notice, this should work in Dataproc. In other cluster you will need to properly  set the cresentials

Comment: Thank you @David Rabinowitz. I tried, but it gave me some error: import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions

scala> val bq = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService() 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/MoreObjects
  at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.<init>(ServiceOptions.java:290)
  ... 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.MoreObjects
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)

Comment: Also, by the way, I cannot find the scala library in the link you provided, could you be more specific?

Comment: There is no Scala API, just Java (which is Scala compatible). The library relies on a recent version of Guava, where spark provides the an ancient version (14.0.1). You can add guava to your project and shade it so it won't collide with Spark's Guava. If you use the spark-bigquery-connector, then you have the bigquery client in the `com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery` (take the spark-bigquery-with-dependencies artifact

Comment: Thank you @David Rabinowitz. Since I cannot control the Scala Version. Could you elaborate the delete table feature by using spark-bigquery-connector? I couldn't find a delete table function through it, but maybe I just missed it somewhere? The link I found online has been notified in my original post.

Comment: It has no relation to the scala version. Please have a look at the revised code sample and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you @David Rabinowitz By using the example code you provided, I got the error shown below: >>> import com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.{BigQueryOptions, TableId}
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.{BigQueryOptions, TableId}
                                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Can you please try with spark-shell first? The above was just tested with Scala 2.11.12 and spark 2.4.5

Comment: Thank you soooo much. It worked. The issue was mine. I tried it in a wrong platform.